# SQL Server DAC - Connection Issue

Tags: sql-server, connectivity, connections, dac

I am having a strange issue when trying to connect to my SQL Server instance remotely from my client computer. I am able to do this on my other instances by opening up a new Database Engine Query and PREFIXING ADMIN: in front of my server name. It only doesnt work on one instance. When I open up the Error Log, it states that "Dedicated admin connection support was established for listening remotely on port 55632." SQL Server Browser is running (and Restarted). When I try to connect to DAC on this one instance, I get an error saying to look in my SQL error logs.this is where I am getting confused:
[image: Error log complaining about DB that does not exist]

I had installed a Monitoring solution from SolarWinds (DPA Free) last week. I didnt find it very useful so I uninstalled it and deleted the database where it stores the metrics (ignite_DBAnalyzer). I double-checked that this DB does not exist on this instance. This is the same DB, ignite_DBAnalyzer, it is claiming it cannot explicitly open (See line 1 of error log). I checked my user Mappings and that DB is not anywhere to be found. I checked my default DB to connect to when i start a new connection and that is also fine.

Has anyone seen this kind of behavior before? Is there cache somewhere I need to clean out so it forgets this DB and can verify that it has been deleted?

Comment: It's because either the connection is set for that database as your initial database or you have the login set as that for your default database.

Comment: I changed my default DB to master just in case that was it, and same error saying cannot explicitly connect to that DB. I am not specifying anywhere actually which DB to use. I checked the Default DB for my SA login and it is also master. Any pointers?

Comment: It's being specified either at the login level or the connection string. Instead of using SSMS which you probably have that cached, use SQLCMD and try again.